# Calling Googlescript Function

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have an external html page that has a script which calls a googlescript that i have publish. How can I call the function deleteunder1minutepassengerinput2() that is also inside my googlescript function? Is it possible to call functions from a published appscript to an external website?

```
<script>
            const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbznVUxr-XONwxuOBtJSQ2xGJs8cUUNFLoAEnThmxOHLN5xg5JO3xnCLUJGnFNaxjP4njg/exec'
            const form = document.forms['google-sheet']
          
            form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
              e.preventDefault()
              fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
                .then(response => { document.getElementById("pasakay-form").reset();window.location.href='https://digitsorani.net/mulawin-pasahero-success/';})
                .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
                document.getElementById("pasakay-form").reset();

            })
          </script>
```

here is my googlescript code:

```
var sheetName = 'Mulawin'
        var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

        function intialSetup () {
          var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
          scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
        }

        function doPost (e) {
          var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
          lock.tryLock(10000)

          try {
            var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
            var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

            var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
            var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

            var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
              return header === 'Timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
            })

            sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

            return ContentService
              .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
              .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
          }

          catch (e) {
            return ContentService
              .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
              .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
          }

          finally {
            lock.releaseLock()
          }
        }

    function deleteunder1minutepassengerinput2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Mulawin');
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows-1 ; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[32] == 'delete') { // This searches all cells in columns A (change to row[1] for columns B and so on) and deletes row if cell is empty or has value 'delete'.
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can call your function `deleteunder1minutepassengerinput2()` from your `doPost(e)` function

You can implement it in such a way that the function is only being called when you pass a certain e.parameter to `doPost` or set this parameter to `true`.

Sample:

```
function doPost (e) {
  // do something
  //...
  if(e.parameter.callDeleteunder1minutepassengerinput2 == true){
    deleteunder1minutepassengerinput2();
  }

}
```